# Linker error if the members are not static in the following Inner-Factory example, why?

Tags: c++, static

I get Linker errors in the following example if I keep the PointFactory member functions as non-static.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class Point {
  private:
    Point(const double x, const double y) :
    x(x), y(y) {}

    class PointFactory {
      public:
        static Point NewCartesian(double x, double y) {
          return {x, y};
        }

        static Point NewPolar(double r, double theta) {
          return {r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)};
        }
    };

  public:
    double x, y;

    // Needs to be friend coz stream object requires access to member variables
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Point const& obj) {
      return os << "x: " << obj.x << " y: " << obj.y;
    }
    
    static PointFactory Factory;
};

int main() {
  auto pt = Point::Factory.NewPolar(5, M_PI_4);
  std::cout << pt << std::endl; 
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Why do I need PointFactory members to be static? What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: The 3rd link of the dupe links contains an answer with the explanation why, as you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Your linker error is caused by the fact that the variable `Factory` is declared in class `Point` but not defined anywhere.

Since class `PointFactory` is private within `Point`, the easiest fix is to change this:

```
static Point::PointFactory Factory;
```

to this:

```
inline static Point::PointFactory Factory;
```

This both declares and defines the variable all in one go, at the cost of requiring C++17.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tehoTSsfdq7NKzfm)

Comment: Thanks, this works and I understand this. I'm looking for reasoning behind how by defining member functions as static overcomes this issue?

Comment: When you do that, the value of `Factory` is never used, so (it would seem) it needn't be defined,